# Data sent over TCPClient to Java Server Socket on Android causes Thread to hang

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I'm creating an Android app which sends Text Messages( SMSManager Class ). This is an app I'm creating for developers, so, the app has to be inter-operable with the various programming languages. The app seems to be working well with JAVA and PHP.

I've been experiencing problems with C#.

```
        TcpClient sock = new TcpClient();
        sock.Connect("192.168.1.24", 5000);
        NetworkStream ns = sock.GetStream();
        String str = "9840486945#hi";
        byte[] by = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
        ns.Write(by, 0, by.Length);
        ns.Read(by, 0, by.Length);             //Will receive "Transmitted" or "Failed"
        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(by);
        Console.WriteLine(returndata);
        if(returndata.Equals("Transmitted"))
        {
             ns.Read(by, 0, by.Length);                     //Will receive "Delivered"
             returndata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(by);
             Console.WriteLine(returndata);
        }
```

On the Android side, I've attempted this:

```
        if(lang.equals("CS"))
        {
            byte[] by=new byte[1024];
            InputStream is;
            try {
                   is = s.getInputStream();
                   is.read(by);
                   input=new String(by);
                } 
             catch (IOException e) 
                {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }
```

I've checked the input coming into the Android app, its perfectly normal. But when I use the input I've received from the socket, the Logcat app's log shows:

```
W/System.err(14636): at com.app.mysmsgateway.Receiver.run(MainActivity.java:498)
```

This is what line 498 contains:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, sentPI, deliverPI);
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Changed encoding on both ends to UTF-8. Still showing me the System.err.

Comment: Post the full logcat. We don't even know what type of exception you get.

Comment: First problem: you're ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read()` and `InputStream.read()` both of which tell you how many bytes you've read. Second problem: you're assuming that you can read all the data you need in a single call. Third problem: you're using the platform default encoding in both codebases - how do you know that'll be the same?

Comment: @PedroOliveira-

I/ActivityManager( 181): Displayed com.app.mysmsgateway/.MainActivity: +1s33ms

Edit: Also the System.err id was 14636, typed in the wrong one by mistake.

Comment: @JonSkeet : There is only one Input which I provide for which I get 3 kinds of outputs.

Input: phonenumber#message

Outputs:

1. Transmitted.
2. Failed.
3. Transmitted. Delivered.

I looked around the Internet and I think the encoding C# and Java uses on its strings are UTF-16?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Looks like I went wrong. defaultCharacterEncoding by property: Cp1252
defaultCharacterEncoding by charSet: windows-1252. 

Got this from running a piece Java code.

Comment: @user3688781: If you're using Android, I very much doubt that that's going to be using CP1252. The whole point if it being the *system* default is that it depends on the *system*. You can't work out the default on your Android phone by running Java code from the desktop on Windows, for example. I *strongly* recommend that you use a fixed encoding, ideally UTF-8.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Yeah, I realized my mistake. I tried UTF-8, but still no change with the error. I'm new to C# can you point me to a reliable resource where I can learn as to how sockets work in c#?

Comment: I don't think this is a socket-specific issue. Note that I talked about 3 different problems in my initial comment... I don't see any evidence that you've addressed the others.

Comment: I have made changes to the first point you had suggested. I tried changing the encoding to UTF-8 on both sides. But I didn't see any change in the results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, I had set a predefined byte array size, which caused a number of characters with ASCII code 0, which means most of my byte array wasn't filled. Worked around this and solved my problem! Thanks for your time @Jonskeet and @PedroOlivera!